# How to display content If function exist/condition true?

Tags: functions, conditional-content

I've created my custom posts. Data from the same is displayed in let's say single-custom-post.php.

Now to clean that file and to remove 100 lines of code, I want to make a new file (let's call it `custom-header.php`) and then just echo or call that content.

Since I've built custom post as a plugin, ideally would be nice to call it if plugin is active, however I don't know how to finish this because one statement is if myplugin is active but then I would somehow add another statement - function, and here I am lost (below).

I could call it by if function exist, but then i am not sure how do I create that function.

What I did and it does work is this:

- inside `custom-header.php` I've added

  ```
  if ('custom_header_display') { ?>   
      //my code
  } ?>
  ```

and then in `single-custom-post.php` I replaced that 100 lines of code with

```
include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/custom-header.php' );?>
```

So my problem is,  I don't know is this a good way, and if it's not, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

You've got an issue with your code. This code will always return `true` because you're passing a string to it.

```
if ('custom_header_display') { ?>   
    //my code
} ?>
```

You can instead use [`is_plugin_active()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_plugin_active) to check if the plugin is activated.

Quoting the example from the Codex page, your code should be like:

```
<?php

include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
if ( is_plugin_active( 'plugin-directory/plugin-file.php' ) ) {
   // include your file.
}
```

Comment: Hey RRikesh, yea i know that's why I'm confused. Now thing is, i did find the same snippet as you, but I'm not sure what to add here // include your file .  Do i add here content or the content inside another if, for an example if ('custom_header_display') { ?>   ...that's what i am not sure. Check if plugin exist, show content, or check if plugin exist ..check something else, show content..

Comment: No, your `if('customheader_display')` is flawed and should be remove. Add the `include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/custom-header.php' );` part in there